# Fatal error: Port 35729 is already in use

Tags: magento2

Grunt issues following error for grunt watch task:-

> Fatal error: Port 35729 is already in use by another process.

I've closed all other applications such as sublime text but still same error. I'm on `Ubuntu 16.04TLS` and only active application is `PHPStorm`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok so I figured out that it's `livereload` that's using port number `35729` hence `grunt watch` can't use the same port and issues the error. To rectify this and since I don't use livereload (favor browsersync) I changed `watch.js` file line 30 `livereload: true` to `liereload: false`.

If however you need to use `livereload` you may specify the port number so replace `livereload: true` to something like `livereload: 12345`. Please note I've not tested this method as I don't use livereload.

Comment: Just tested it by changing  'updater' and 'reload' tasks in `watch.js` file, if you specify different ports for each this error will resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Run lsof | grep 35729 and perhaps netstat -plunt to check for something on that port. Something is probably still on it even though you've closed everything obvious.